# Java VKAPI SDK - Авторизация при помощи логина/пароля

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, vk-sdk

Я читаю документацию по VK_API Java SDK, вот дошло дело до авторизации, конкретно мне нужно авторизироваться под своей страницей, но в документации написано, что бы это сделать, нужны APP_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI, code, а я если честно без понятия что это и откуда брать. В доках ничего не сказано про авторизацию просто по логину и паролю, только вот так:[image: Текст из документации]

Можно ли как то авторизоваться через логин и пароль, или только таким образом?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то тут имеется в виду, что авторизоваться надо вручную в браузере, после чего он перенаправит вас на redirectUri, куда пришлёт `auth_code`, который вы из параметра урлы на сервере вытащите и обменяете через API на токен.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а можно как то без этих танцев с бубном? Допустим в Python, я могу авторизоваться в три строчки, и с логина/пароля, и с токена

Comment: Вроде бы без бубна нельзя) Вроде бы SDK для Java не поддерживает этого.

Comment: Huh, хорошо, спасибо